# Creating a skeleton from a text file

Tags: c#, kinect

I want to create a skeleton from a text file containing joint/x/y/z
I have issues creating the joints

```
string[] JointPoints = line.Split('/');
float x = (float)Convert.ToDouble(JointPoints[1]);
float y = (float)Convert.ToDouble(JointPoints[2]);
float z = (float)Convert.ToDouble(JointPoints[3]);
Joint j = new Joint();
var pos = j.Position;

switch (JointPoints[0].ToUpper())
{
case "HEAD":
//j.JointType = JointType.Head; <--- Can't do this, 
pos.X = x;pos.Y = y;pos.Z = z;
playSkeleton.Joints[JointType.Head] = j;
break;
```

Comment: What **exactly** is the issue? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: Post your definitions of Joint and JointType.

Comment: Issue was making Joint j the correct type of joint,sorry for stating the question so badly, I solved this by making `j = playSkeleton.Joints[JointType.Head]` in the place of the code that I commented out